# How can i set onchange in a map with React for Switch Buttons from React-Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to set the `onChange` event for each checkbox which i create in a `map` function.
Unfortunately if i click on one checkbox i got the right target id, but all checkboxes are toggle not the one which was clicked.
So how can i handle that ?

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        user: [],
        checked: ''
    }
    this.handeClick = this.handeClick.bind(this);
}

handeClick(e) {
    console.log("Wurde geklickt: " + e.target.id);
    const item = e.target.name;
    const isChecked = e.target.checked;
    this.setState({ checked: isChecked });
}

[...]

render() {
    return (
        <>
            <Container fluid className="con">
                <Row className="justify-content-md-center">
                    {
                        this.state.user.map(user => {
                            return (
                                <Col md="3" key={user.SD_Emplid}>
                                    <div className="card">
                                        {user.SD_Anrede} <h2>{user.SD_Vorname}</h2>  <h4>{user.SD_Vorname}</h4>
                                        <hr></hr>
                                        <Form.Check
                                            onChange={this.handeClick}
                                            checked={this.state.checked}
                                            className="checkBoxCard"
                                            type="switch"
                                            id={user.SD_Emplid}
                                            label=""
                                        />
                                    </div>
                                </Col>
                            )
                        })
                    }
                </Row>
            </Container>
        </>
    )
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store the `checked` state per `user id`. A possible solution would be to use an `object` where the `keys` are the `user ids` and the values are the checked states. If the `key` is not present this is equivalent to *unchecked*:

```
handeClick(e) {
    console.log("Wurde geklickt: " + e.target.id);
    const item = e.target.name;
    const isChecked = e.target.checked;

    this.setState(
        ({checked}) => ({
            checked: {
                ...checked,
                [e.target.id]: isChecked,
            }
        })
    );
}
```

Then you can set the `checked` state of your checkboxes from the state:

```
{this.state.user.map(user => (
    <Col md="3" key={user.SD_Emplid}>
        <div className="card">
            {user.SD_Anrede} 
            <h2>{user.SD_Vorname}</h2>  
            <h4>{user.SD_Vorname}</h4>
            <hr></hr>
            <Form.Check
                onChange={this.handeClick}
                checked={!!this.state.checked[user.SD_Emplid]}
                className="checkBoxCard"
                type="switch"
                id={user.SD_Emplid}
                label=""
            />
        </div>
    </Col>
)}
```

Make sure to init your `checked` state as an object:

```
this.state = {
      user: [],
      checked: {},
}
```

Comment: Can you explain, what setState ...checked does  ?

Comment: @ben88 It is the callback version of `setState`. The callback function takes the current state and returns the next state. In this case it takes the current state's `checked` object and spreads it into a new one replacing the key in `e.target.id` with the value of `isChecked`. So it basically creates a copy of the old state replacing the value of the item keyed by `e.target.id` with the value of `isChecked`. EDIT: `...checked` spreads all properties of the the object into the new one.

Answer (score 1):

Your state checked is a boolean type. Each item will just check if checked is true and if you mark just one, all of them will be checked.

May you need to change your state, checked function, and how item known if it is checked. like this:

```js
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
      user: [],
      checked: []

  }


  this.handeClick = this.handeClick.bind(this);
}


handeClick(e) {
  console.log("Wurde geklickt: " + e.target.id);
  const checked = this.state.checked;

  if (checked.includes(e.target.id)) {
    newChecked = checked.filter(id => id !== e.target.id)
    this.setState({ checked: newChecked })
  } else {
    checked.push(e.target.value);
    this.setState({ checked })
  }
}

[...]




render() {
  const { checked } = this.state;
  return (
      <>
          <Container fluid className="con">
              <Row className="justify-content-md-center">

                  {
                      this.state.user.map(user => {
                          return (
                              <Col md="3" key={user.SD_Emplid}>
                                  <div className="card">
                                      {user.SD_Anrede} <h2>{user.SD_Vorname}</h2>  <h4>{user.SD_Vorname}</h4>
                                      <hr></hr>
                                      <Form.Check
                                          onChange={this.handeClick}
                                          checked={checked.includes(user.SD_Emplid)}
                                          className="checkBoxCard"
                                          type="switch"
                                          id={user.SD_Emplid}
                                          label=""

                                      />
                                  </div>
                              </Col>
                          )
                      })
                  }
              </Row>
          </Container>

      </>
  )
}

}
```

Comment: `push()` is mutating the state. You should use `[...checked, e.target.checked]` instead.

Comment: Yes, you can use this way, but push is not mutating the state. I had copy the state in a const called checked. `const checked = this.state.checked`. I just forgot to use destructuring. `const { checked } = this.state;`

Comment: `checked` will be a reference to the same object in the state in both cases. You would have to do `const checked = [...this.state.checked]` to create a copy.

Comment: Right! Understood now.